# Debug java product without eclipse etc

Tags: java, debugging

I faced strange problem in Sonar (code analysis tool) and do not understand why it is faile. It is started using command line:

```
%JAVA_EXEC% %SONAR_OPTIONS% -cp "%SONAR_RUNNER_HOME%\lib\sonar-runner-dist-2.3.jar" "-Drunner.home=%SONAR_RUNNER_HOME%" "-Dproject.home=%PROJECT_HOME%" org.sonar.runner.Main %*
```

I am not Java programmer, but I would like to debug this process somehow. I know that error appears inside one of loaded plugins, not inside sonar itself.

Question: is there way to start java application with debugging availability without eclipse and any other special and very massive editor? Something command line'ed with ability to set breakpoint, inspect variable value and stepping forward/stepping over is enough for me.

Comment: I would assume beyond print statements

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot I do not want to download entire codebase and rebuild it - it may be another question from non-java-developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's JDB, the [Java Debugger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html) from the official SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add this parameter to invoked command and connect to this process with prefered debugger (Eclipse, IntelliJ or what you want)

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

You can debug this remotelly!

Comment: Thanks. May be there is more much simpler way to debug witout eclipse/intellij? It is too big.

Comment: So go to @Joachim Rohde answer, it is for you! :) But I think this can be hard also and no so easy :)